# Set and print array objects in angular 4?

Tags: angular

When click in angular 4 i want to console log the value of array having objects in it

```
showModal(i){
  let set = {
    product: 1, // in future it will be i not fixed 1
    quantity: 1
  }
   let itemss= this.selected.push(set);
   let  logss= console.log(itemss); // returning 1


  this._storage.set('prd', JSON.stringify(itemss));
  this._storage.get('prd').then((item) =>{
     console.log(item[0]); // also returning 1
  });
}
```

i want to console log the objects as in JavaScript when i write

```
var sample =[];
var set = {
    product: 1,
    quantity: 1
}
var s= sample.push(set);
console.log(s[0]);
```

in JavaScript it is returning {product:1, quantity:1}

Comment: `console.log(item)` You get an object back in the promise. If you want that object in an array again have to push it in again.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Could you be more elaborative?

Comment: i did the `console.log(item)` but same issue returning 1 @Swoox

Comment: `let itemss= this.selected.push(set);` === 1
You have to do `this.selected.push(set)` without items.
Then `this._storage.set('prd', JSON.stringify(this.selected))`. Or `this.selected.push(set)` `let itemss= this.selected`

Comment: @Swoox Thanks it's working fine now ... one more question 
how can i set 
`var set = {
product+i : i
quantity : 1
}`

actually setting ` product+i ` giving me error
when write only "i" returning string "i" not dynamic value return by the function

Comment: @AHP I would do `var set = { product = i, quantity : 1 }` if you do a `*ngFor="let item of items"` then **item.product === i** (in html)

Comment: @Swoox can you provide me an example of shopping cart having detail how to add products to cart....

Answer (score 1):

1. the push functions returns nothing. Meaning

```
let itemss= this.selected.push(set);
```

Certainly won't display your array.

2. In your code, item isn't set. So using

```
console.log(item[0]);
```

Won't return your result.

3. Y'oure pushing an object into an array. Meaning you actually have

```
let data = [
    {product: 1, quantity: 1}
];
```

Meaning your log is correct.

4. Here are all the displays you can have

```
console.log(items); // [{product: 1, quantity: 1}]
console.log(items[0]); // {product: 1, quantity: 1}
console.log(items[0].quantity); // 1
console.log(items[0].product); // 1
```